# Preventing new user misinterpreting intent of advice offered and leaving site?

Tags: discussion

I've been trying to help answer a question titled [Regional Large Scale Map Projection Choice](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116934/regional-large-scale-map-projection-choice) but am having difficulty providing an adequate answer, or explaining that maybe the OP doesn't understand his own knowledge limits.

Now he appears to want to give up in disgust.

I know I am not always the most tactful.

Can anyone add some new perspective or damage control, please?

Comment: For immediate damage control, I removed the final line of the answer, which added no information or useful advice but served only to offend the OP. Your post otherwise is a great one, filled with useful advice and responding more than adequately to a somewhat confused statement of the question. It would be a nice gesture on your part simply to apologize for any ill feelings.

Answer (score 2):

When I first saw that question I very nearly closed it as a duplicate of [Choosing projected coordinate system for mapping all US states?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104005/which-projected-coordinate-system-should-be-used-for-mapping-the-us) but I left it open to see what the community thought.

Reading it again, I still think it should be made a duplicate of that same question.

Sometimes the asker and the answerer(s) are coming from such different directions that it is hard to find the common ground that leads to a nice "clean" Q&A and so at times we will lose users.

Fortunately, for each one we lose, we seem to be gaining many more.

Nevertheless, I hope that the user will reflect on the time you spent trying to help, and the skills and experience you brought to that Q&A, and decides to give the site another shot.